# Android Softkeyboard shift key Press throws Exception dispatching input event

Tags: android

I have created a custom softkeyboard. All other keys are working perfectly except shift key. When I press the shift key I'm getting the following error.

```
01-01 02:17:06.543  23608-23608/? E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
01-01 02:17:06.544  23608-23608/? E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-01 02:17:06.570  23608-23608/? E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
            at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.adjustCase(KeyboardView.java:580)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onBufferDraw(KeyboardView.java:690)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.invalidateKey(KeyboardView.java:1057)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1351)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1212)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:765)
            at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:93)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4023)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3504)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3580)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3637)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3504)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5703)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5793)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-01 02:17:06.570  23608-23608/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-01 02:17:06.586  23608-23608/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sundarsingh.customkeyboard, PID: 23608
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
            at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:494)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.adjustCase(KeyboardView.java:580)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onBufferDraw(KeyboardView.java:690)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.invalidateKey(KeyboardView.java:1057)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1351)
            at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1212)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:765)
            at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:93)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4023)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3504)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3580)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3637)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3504)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3478)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3451)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5703)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5793)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: as error suggested your string array in getting out of bound . may be you are calling position of value from array that is not available.